# Чи є різниця між словами "калюжа", "калабаня" та "ковбаня"?

Tags: вживання-слів, росіянізм

Цікавить чи є якась різниця у вживанні слів "[калабаня](http://sum.in.ua/s/kalabanja)", "[ковбаня](http://sum.in.ua/s/kovbanja)" та "[калюжа](http://sum.in.ua/s/kaljuzha)". Всі ці слова знаходимо в СУМі, і якщо біля слова "калабаня" бачимо, що це діалектизм, то біля слів "ковбаня" (раніше такого слова не доводилося зустрічати) та "калюжа" таких позначок немає.
На [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8F) також знайшов такі синоніми до цих слів, як "[баюра](http://sum.in.ua/s/bajura)", "[барліг](http://sum.in.ua/s/barligh)", "[калабатина](http://sum.in.ua/s/kalabatyna)" (також має позначку, що це діалектизм), "[бакай](http://sum.in.ua/s/bakaj)" (діал.) та "[ковтьоба](http://sum.in.ua/s/kovtjoba)" (діал.). Вони також є в СУМі.

Отож, виходить слів, які б означали "заглибина в ґрунті, наповнена водою або іншою рідиною" дуже багато в українській мові. Однак, цікаво які з них краще вживати в творах ЗНО. І якщо з тими словами, у яких є позначка "діал.", ще все зрозуміло, то як бути із такими, як "калюжа" (спершу думав, що це росіянізм, але прочитавши цю [статтю](https://day.kyiv.ua/uk/article/istoriya-i-ya/pravda-istoriyi-ta-mifi-movoznavstva), я виявив, що саме слово "лужа" було утворено від українського варіанту), "ковбаня", "баюра" та "барліг"? Чи є між цими словами якась значна різниця, чи ми можемо без сумнівів вживати всі ці слова?

Comment: Дуже хороше питання, дякую. Хочу запропонувати до використання ще неповний, але новіший словник СУМ-20, всі слова, які ви шукали для цього питання, там вже є: http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl. Якщо він вам буде до вподоби, виділіть, будь ласка, кілька хвилин, щоб поставити посилання саме на нього.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В принципі значної різниці між цими словами немає. Ви можете вживати кожне з цих слів у повсякденному житті. Головне, щоб вас розуміли. Наприклад, "барліг" у своєму четвертому словниковому значенні особисто мені був невідомим.

> БАРЛІ́Г, лога і логу, чол.
>
> 4. Болото; калюжа.

Також треба відзначити, що деякі з цих слів мають відтінки у значенні. Наприклад, "ковбаня" згідно з словником - саме вибоїна, в той час як "калюжа" може бути просто водою, розлитою на поверхні; "баюра" ж має значення саме великої калюжі.

Щодо ЗНО, то я раджу використовувати "сухіші" й найпоширеніші синоніми слів, оскільки власне висловлення у форматі ЗНО не передбачає перевірку творчості у тексті, а лише дотримання правопису та форми, передбаченої ЗНО.